# Adding a footnote to a single row label in a gtsummary table

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt, footnotes

I'm trying to add a footnote to a row label of a [`gtsummary`](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/) table, but I can't figure out how to reference the exact cell I want.

**Intended output**

Usint the default `trial` dataset, I'd like to add a footnote to "Drug B" that reads "i.e. placebo":

| Characteristic | N = 200¹ |
| --- | --- |
| Chemotherapy Treatment |  |
| __ Drug A | 98 (49%) |
| __ Drug B*²* | 102 (51%) |
| ¹ n (%) |  |
| *² i.e. placebo* |  |

I've tried converting to a `gt` table and then using [`tab_footnote()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_footnote.html) and [`cells_stub()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cells_stub.html), but I don't know how to use `row =`  to reference the specific row label I want.

Unfortunately the documentation example for [`cells_stub()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cells_stub.html) only uses its default `locations = everything()` argument value.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

trial["trt"] |>
        tbl_summary() |>
        as_gt() |>
        tab_footnote(footnote = "i.e. placebo",
                     # Line below doesn't work
                     locations = cells_stub(rows = "Drug B"))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `gtsummary::modify_table_styling()` function to place footnotes in the body of a table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <-
  trial |>
  select(trt) |> 
  tbl_summary() |>
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label,
    rows = label == "Drug B",
    footnote = "i.e. placebo"
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How would I do the same to place the footnote at the variable level (Chemotherapy Treatment)?