# {gtsummary} How to add caption for specific variables?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Let's consider the example below.

```
m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial)
tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[image]

As shown in the image (excuse me for sloppy handwriting), I'd like to add footnote specifically for certain variables. My intinct is to

```
m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial)
tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
modify_footnote(T1 = "ABCDE")
```

But this doesn't work, and looking at available variables to modify:

```
tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
show_header_names()
```

shows only

```
 As a usage guide, the code below re-creates the current column headers.
modify_header(
  label = "**Characteristic**",
  estimate = "**OR**",
  ci = "**95% CI**",
  p.value = "**p-value**"
)


Column Name   Column Header      
------------  -------------------
label         **Characteristic** 
estimate      **OR**             
ci            **95% CI**         
p.value       **p-value**
```

which means there's no variable to modify, not headers.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit:
I'd like to specifically "link" the foornote to "T1" in the figure by showing superscript, as shown in the expected figure (i.e. T1 <sup>a</sup> in the figure, <sup>a</sup> T1 = ABCDE, in the footnote)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have found a way to do this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154658/adding-a-footnote-to-a-single-row-label-in-a-gtsummary-table

Answer (score 2):

Convert to gt table and then modify accordingly.
Hope this helps.

```
tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "T1=abcde")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I'd like to "link" it to "T1" in the figure by showing superscript, as shown in the expected figure (i.e. "T1<sup>a<\sup>" in the figure, and "<sup>a<\sup> T1 = ABCDE" in the footnote. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry typos: (i.e. T1 <sup>a</sup> in the figure, and <sup>a</sup> T1 = ABCDE in the footnote)